# Button not enabling after it is disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, list, controls

I have a List of items that contain people's names. I have made it so that once the end of the list is reached, the button becomes disabled so that it is clear that there are no more items left. The issue is when I go back to previous item, the button remains disabled even though I have re-enabled it...

So I have method that disables/enables button and there is a call to this method in button_click event handler:

```
public void DisableButton()
{
    if(birthdays.IsThereAnotherItem())
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (!birthdays.IsThereAnotherItem())
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
    }           
}
```

I have also activated the button_EnabledChanged event handler.

I go back to previous item like this...

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    birthdays.StepToPreviousPerson();
    DisplayPeople();      
}
```

Comment: Why not `btnNext.Enabled = birthdays.IsThereAnotherItem();` and drop all `if`s?

Comment: how do you "o back to previous item" ? you should include this method also in this function/method

Comment: @DmitryBychenko same result...(button does disable at end of List but doesn't enable again).

Comment: @MongZhu updated my post

Comment: You use DisableButton() to both disable and enable the button - confusing naming. Anyway, are you sure this function is being called when the user clicks on the Previous button? I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: since it is still the same, the problem is in the code of wither `IsThereAnotherItem` or `StepToPreviousPerson`. Please post this also

Answer (score 1):

When you have to check for disabling `btnNext` button? On `birthday` *selected item changed*. `btnNext` should be disabled if and only if the last item is selected.

Assuming `birthday` is a `ListBox` and `SelectionMode` is `SelectionMode.One` you can put it like this:

```
   private void birthday_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Previous is Enabled if and only if the selected item is not first one
     btnPrevious.Enabled = birthday.SelectedIndex > 0; 

     // btnNext is enabled if and only if
     //   1. birthday has items (not empty)
     //   2. An item selected
     //   3. The item is not the last one 
     btnNext.Enabled = birthday.SelectedIndex >= 0 && // an item selected
                       birthday.SelectedIndex < birthday.Items.Count - 1;
   }
```

So you have both `btnNext` and `btnPrevious` updated whenever `birthday` selection changed (by whatever reason - `StepToPreviousPerson`, `StepToNextPerson` calls, direct selection etc.)

Comment: Check for disabling button when 'Next' or 'Previous' buttons are selected (sorry I have not shown them here). 'birthday' is not a list box, its simply a text box.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it based on @Eli's comment. I had to put the function call for DisableButton() in the 'btnPrevious' event handler as well as the 'Next' button event handler, which I already had. Very simple thing that I missed out from the beginning.

Thanks to everyone who helped out.